# How to find the top n most popular Sport from a list, inside a list of Student in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like find out the top(N) most popular sports practiced by students.
n is given as a parameter.

I have made this in 3 steps but I am not satisfied with the solution. I am trying to make it one go

This is my complete code and solution :

```
public class Person {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private List<Sport> sports = new ArrayList<>();

   //getter and setters + constructor
}
```

This is Class Sport :

```
public class Sport {

    private String name;

    public Sport(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is my data and the logic to extract the top 3 most popular sports:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // most popular sports

        Sport football = new Sport("Football");
        Sport tennis = new Sport("Tennis");
        Sport basketBall = new Sport("BasketBall");
        Sport handball = new Sport("Handball");
        Sport swimming = new Sport("Swimming");
        Sport running = new Sport("Running");
        Sport climbing = new Sport("Climbing");


        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Bob", Arrays.asList(football, handball)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Tom", Arrays.asList(football, basketBall, tennis)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Tim", Arrays.asList(climbing, handball, football)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Marc", Arrays.asList(football, basketBall)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Gerard", Arrays.asList(tennis, handball)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Claudia", Arrays.asList(running, handball)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Sara", Arrays.asList(football, climbing)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Laura", Arrays.asList(football)));
        people.add(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Mo", Arrays.asList(football, tennis)));


        //Step 1 - Merge all the sports lists of all students
        List<Sport> allSports = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person person : people) {
            allSports.addAll(person.getSports());
        }

        // Step 2 - Transfor into a Map with groupBy and count
        Map<Sport, Long> collect = allSports.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

        // Return top 3 most popular sports
        collect.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<Sport, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .limit(3)
                .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getKey().getName()));

    }
```

Output :

```
 Football
 Handball
 Tennis
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Andronicus , It's too verbose..maybe something more elegant or shorter. Also, I am not comfortable with merging all the lists into one. Would it still be okay if I had millions of entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using a third-party library, you can use the methods `countByEach` and `topOccurrences` from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
MutableList<Person> people = Lists.mutable.with(
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Bob", football, handball),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Tom", football, basketBall, tennis),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Tim", climbing, handball, football),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Marc", football, basketBall),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Gerard", tennis, handball),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Claudia", running, handball),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Sara", football, climbing),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Laura", football),
        new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "Mo", football, tennis));

MutableList<String> top3Names =
        people.countByEach(Person::getSports)
                .topOccurrences(3)
                .collect(pair -> pair.getOne().getName());

MutableList<String> expected =
        Lists.mutable.with("Football", "Handball", "Tennis");

Assert.assertEquals(expected, top3Names);
```

The type `MutableList` extends `List` and adds additional APIs. I simplified the Person constructor to take a var arg array of `Sport`. The method `countByEach` returns a `MutableBag`. The method `topOccurrences` returns a `MutableList` of `ObjectIntPair` of `Sport`.

You can also use Java Streams with the `Collectors2` utility class from Eclipse Collections as follows:

```
List<String> top3Names = people.stream()
        .collect(Collectors2.countByEach(Person::getSports))
        .topOccurrences(3)
        .collect(pair -> pair.getOne().getName());

List<String> expected =
        Arrays.asList("Football", "Handball", "Tennis");

Assert.assertEquals(expected, top3Names);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Comment: Thanks Donald. I like the topOccurrences and countByEach  of Eclipse. You example is less verbose and has a better readability. What would you answer when some people reject the use of third party libraries...I know for a fact my colleagues/team lead would hate that lol

Comment: One more question Donald.  Is the the MutableList  supports thread safety ? Would I need it for the add() operations ?

Comment: My usual answer: https://medium.com/oracledevs/ten-reasons-to-use-eclipse-collections-91593104af9d?source=friends_link&sk=e757519e99cc2cea9d73f1d93d6190a3

Comment: An answer from the community: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333372/is-there-any-disadvantage-to-using-eclipse-collections-exclusively

Comment: You can return a synchronized view for a MutableList by calling asSynchronized. This will provide conditional thread safety (iterators need precaution).  Alternatively, there is Lists.multiReader.with(...) which returns a MultiReaderList, which extends MutableList. MultiReaderList throws on calls to iterator, if you don't protect the calls using withReadLockAndDelegate or withWriteLockAndDelegate.

Comment: If you don't need to mutate the list after creation, and want to make sure it isn't modified then you can use `Lists.immutable.with()`

Answer (score 7):

A single pipeline for that would look like:

```
people.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getSports().stream()) // step 1 (stream of Sport)
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting())) // step 2 (map with count)
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Sport, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(3)
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey().getName()) // mapped to speficic type before accessing
        .forEach(System.out::println); // step 3 (print top N entry names)
```

Comment: Hey Naman, awesome, thanks ! One more  question pelase. Is there a way I can return an Array or a List of the top n preferred, instead of a System.out::println ?

Comment: @Naman quite a lot of sorting, for only n (a lot less than total, potentially) elements...

Comment: @ErEcTuS To get a list, replace the last forEach by .collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: @Eugene, good remark. It will count if I had millions of records..I don't want to sort all of them while only needing top 5 per say

Comment: @ErEcTuS To return, you can `collect` after the `limit(N)` operation based on what you want to return.

Comment: @Eugene At work, I have explored implementing `TopNPriorityQueue` for such use case, but that is in itself decent code introduction and complexity. For something already existing, I would prefer using such an approach.

Comment: @Naman rightz merely suggesting an alternate approach is already a step in the proper direction, if needed.